# Setting predefined scale in QGIS Atlas

Tags: qgis, scale, atlas

I want to generate an Atlas in QGIS using a fixed scale of 1:750 on each page. I am using a point file to define page location centers. 
Both 'Margin around feature' and 'Predefined scale (best fit)' are greyed out but using 'Fixed scale' even when I set the scale to 1:750, when I switch pages the scale reverts to 1:3412.
I have added 1:750 scale in Project properties but nothing seems to change.
I am using QGIS 2.18.12

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have fixed itself by restarting the project and setting the scale first before enabling Atlas generation.